# Is there a way to save the style as a new code with the new style? PINE SCRIPT TRADINGVIEW

Tags: styles, pine-script

I have an indicator that would like to modify its code, I have the source (code).

When I go to configuration options a window opens in which I modify its configuration in (data entry) and (style).

Is there a way to save the style as a new code with the new style?

I don't know much about style.

I will appreciate your help please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about changing the settings permanently from the code? Yes you can,it would help you more but I lack information about your problem

Comment: I have modified an indicator from the style window but now I need to modify it in the code so it saves the code with the new style.

Where can I find more information to save the styles or learn more about them?

In my profile are my contact information, if you can contact me I will thank you very much. sergiolazarte2006@gmail.com